# Gradle extension properties in subproject

Tags: java, gradle, build, properties

I have a Java project (builded with Gradle 4.6) which contains few modules and every module has it's own build.gradle. Also there is build.gradle in the main project. So the structure looks like:

```
/
/build.gradle
/module-number-one/build.gradle
/module-number-two/build.gradle
```

Everything works good, but I cannot access extension properties from main script. For example in `/module-number-one/build.gradle` I have:

```
ext {
   myProp = 'some value'
}
```

And when I do:

```
allprojects.findAll { Project project ->
    println(project.ext.has('myProp'))
    // or
    println(project.hasProperty('myProp'))
    // or
    println(project
        .getExtensions()
        .getExtraProperties()
        .getProperties()
        .contains('myProp'))
}
```

I receiving false. Is it possible to access ext only from the same file or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the project property evaluation, if you put the property reference after the `project.afterEvaluate`, it should work:

```
task findModule {
    subprojects {
        project -> project.afterEvaluate {
            println(project.name + ": " + project.ext.has('cons'))
            println(project.name + ": " + project.hasProperty('cons'))
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ gradle -q findModule
module-number-one: true
module-number-one: true
module-number-two: false
module-number-two: false
```

Comment: Please note, that the task in the example is completely irrelevant and won't do anything!

Comment: @lu.koerfer what do you mean?

Comment: Just execute `gradle -q` without the task `findModule` and the output will be the same. Because you are using the task configuration closure, which will always be executed. Either use `doFirst` or `doLast` closure (this way you won't need `afterEvaluate`) or just remove the task and put the code anywhere in your buildscript.